# javascript copy text from element into textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ckeditor, inline

I'm using CKEditor Inline mod and I am trying to save this into database. I have an idea about copy text from element to textarea. I have element `div#textToBeSaved` and I want to copy all text from this element into textarea with name `content` immediately.

Header:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/administration/aditional/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() { copyText(); },500);

    function copyText() {    
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved.getData();
        document.getElementsByName("content")[0].value = data;
    }
  </script>
```

Text:

```
    <div id="textToBeSaved">
     <div id="content-full">
      <div class="container">
       {P_CONTENT}
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
```

`{P_CONTENT}` is parsed in PHP. For example `{P_CONTENT}` returns `<p contenteditable='true'>hello world</p>`

I just need save everything in the element **#textToBeSaved** into database with actual data.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide us some sample code that you've tried or that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer.

`<div id="textToBeSaved">
         <div id="content-full">
          <div class="container">
           <p>Hello world</p>
          </div>
         </div>
</div>

<textarea><p>Hello world</p></textarea>
`

And if I edit any content into element <div id="textToBeSaved"></div> (using CKEditor Inline editing) i will see the same content in my textarea immediately.

Comment: You mean you want the HTML content of textToBeSaved to be copied in real-time to #content as the user types?

Comment: Yes. And #content is textarea.

Answer (score 0):

If your CKEditor has an id of `textToBeSaved` then this code will get the contents of the CKEditor for you and copy them into your `content` element:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() { copyText(); },500);

    function copyText() {    
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved.getData();
        document.getElementsByName("content")[0].value = data;
    }
</script>
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my textarea still not changed.

Comment: Edit your question to provide your full code including how you initialize CKEditor.

Comment: try `setTimeout(function() { copyText(); },500);`

Comment: Actually, you're not even intializing CKEditor... Is the CKEditor being rendered?

Comment: Still not working. CKeditor is working. I can edit text, but i need it to save into my textarea.

Answer (score 0):

By the way CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved.getData(); is undefined. I think it's because element textToBeSaved isn't defined as editable. But I can't mark it as editable 'cause I don't want to make everything editable in this element. Here's a picture [LINK](http://www.imgbank.cz/images/2013/08/15/problem.jpg)

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the id of the element that you're editing (the one with the contentEditable attribute). If you refer to something else it's obvious that it can't work.

Comment: I did it, but content in my textarea wasn't updated. Probably i'll wait for update by CKSource mod for better saving content with Inline mode.

Comment: I don't think that CKSource needs to do anything here because what you want it's easily doable right now, you just have to fix your javascript to work with your markup.